# Getting error while running appium test on Android - Failed configuration

Tags: appium-android, appium-java

My appium test cases are running fine for mobile automation and all of a sudden getting error for all test cases.

Below is the response

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass ConfigureAppium
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The session identified by 75ad261c-e451-4504-8a07-92aa6195faf9 is not known
Host info: host: 'WINL0PF27XF4G', ip: '10.126.53.194'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:deviceName=Emulator1, platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=C://Users//z0049922//eclipse-workspace//Appium//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//z0049922//eclips..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Emulator1, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//z0049922//eclips..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Emulator1, platformName: ANDROID}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:194)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:80)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:92)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:117)
at Srivalli.BaseTest.ConfigureAppium(BaseTest.java:30)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: AppiumTest
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The session identified by 75ad261c-e451-4504-8a07-92aa6195faf9 is not known
Host info: host: 'WINL0PF27XF4G', ip: '10.126.53.194'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:deviceName=Emulator1, platformName=ANDROID, appium:automationName=UIAutomator2, appium:app=C://Users//z0049922//eclipse-workspace//Appium//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//z0049922//eclips..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Emulator1, platformName: ANDROID}}]
Capabilities {appium:app: C://Users//z0049922//eclips..., appium:automationName: UIAutomator2, appium:deviceName: Emulator1, platformName: ANDROID}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:194)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:80)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:92)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:117)
at Srivalli.BaseTest.ConfigureAppium(BaseTest.java:30)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue my self, restarting the mobile device worked for me.